# How to get the /storage/emulated/0 using Context.getExternalFilesDirs(String), Context.getExternalCacheDirs()

Tags: android, android-file

if i use the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, i am getting the /storage/emulated/0 correctly. But the  getExternalStorageDirectory is get deprecated so, i am trying to achive this using the `Context.getExternalFilesDirs(String), Context.getExternalCacheDirs()`. i am getting like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.statussaver`. basically it return the current application file directory. How to get the /storage/emulated/0 using Context Api. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well you can take the part before /Android...

Comment: Just use getExternalStorageDirectory or getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(). They are deprecated but work fine.

Comment: @blackapps yes, works fine deprecated method. For my use cases, I need to get the WhatsApp status location. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() if use this means i am getting /storage/emulated/0 this and i will append the /WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses. if i use this Context.getExternalCacheDirs() means i getting /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.statussaver. is there is any way to achive Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() exact replacement for this.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you need more.

Comment: @blackapps without deprecated method(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()). i need to get the /storage/emulated/0 the directory.

Comment: Look at my first comment.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to get that value anymore, because from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory())

> When an app targets `Build.VERSION_CODES.Q`, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps

That means even if you have gotten the same path it will be useless to you. Depending on your use case you should use one of the strategies outlined in https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared instead.

> Android provides APIs for storing and accessing the following types of shareable data:
>
> - Media content: The system provides standard public directories for these kinds of files, so the user has a common location for all their photos, another common location for all their music and audio files, and so on. Your app can access this content using the platform's [`MediaStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore) API.
> - Documents and other files: The system has a special directory for containing other file types, such as PDF documents and books that use the EPUB format. Your app can access these files using the platform's Storage Access Framework.
> - Datasets: On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, the system caches large datasets that multiple apps might use. These datasets can support use cases like machine learning and media playback. Apps can access these shared datasets using the [`BlobStoreManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/blob/BlobStoreManager) API.
>
> For more information about these APIs, see the following guides:
>
> - [Media content](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)
> - [Documents and other files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files)
> - [Datasets](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/datasets)

Comment: `the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps` Well that is not true for apps on an Android 11 device. Just using the File class list() method will deliver all directories on it like Download, Documents, DCIM, Pictures and so on. And one can create its own folders in those public directories and create files in those folders like before.